# Newbie Trying to re-create Simple Playlist Manager from Ch 3 of OREILLY's "Head First HTML5 Programming"

Tags: javascript, html

The title pretty much says it all. I'm a newbie who really loves computers, video games, & robots...anything digital. Anywho, I've just recently gotten into programming because I was thinking about making my own website & I want it to be as awesome as possible. Not to mention, it's a pretty good skill to have. I'd definitely make more designing sites than working the crummy job I have now. But I digress, I took this code from Ch 3 of OREILLY's "Head First HTML5 Programming". I made a "few" adjustments, but nothing major. As you see, it's merely a simple little playlist manager with a few functions & alerts. At 1st glance, the page looks as it should. But when you type in a song & click the "Add Song" button...NOTHING HAPPENS!! Also, the "alerts" DON'T WORK!! Why?! What did I do wrong?! Minus a few irrelevant & "intentional" customization I made to it, it's the same formula used in the book & it should work. "Each" time someone enters a song, "ul.appendChild(li)" should add it to the playlist...RIGHT?!?! Well anyway, here's the html/javascript:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>RTH</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>

window.onload = init;

function init() {

Var button = document.getElementById("addButton");

button.onclick = handleButtonClick;

}


function handleButtonClick() {

var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");

var songName = textInput.value;

} if (songName == "") {

alert("Enter a track!");

} else {

alert("Congrats...track is now being added!");

}


var li = document.createElement("li");

li.innerHTML = songName;

var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");

ul.appendChild(li);

}

</script>
<body>
<form>

<Input type = "text" Id = "songTextInput" size = "40" placeholder = "Insert track here...">

<Input type = "button" id = "addButton" value = "Add Song">


</form>
<strong>

<ul id="playlist">


</ul>
</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You'll have to take a look at any errors that come up. You'll be able to see these errors with a browser plugin like [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for Firefox, or the Chrome Inspector (comes pre-installed) on Chrome. If installed, you can access them both using the F12 key.

Comment: you have entire if else out side of your function remove { in the third line of handleButtonClick.

Answer (score 1):

Hi the modified code is,

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>RTH</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script>


function handleButtonClick() {

var textInput = document.getElementById("songTextInput");

var songName = textInput.value;

 if (songName == "") {

alert("Enter a track!");

} else {

alert("Congrats...track is now being added!");

}


var li = document.createElement("li");

li.innerHTML = songName;

var ul = document.getElementById("playlist");

ul.appendChild(li);

}

</script>
<body>
<form>

<Input type = "text" Id = "songTextInput" size = "40" placeholder = "Insert track here..."/>

<Input type = "button" id = "addButton" onclick="handleButtonClick();" value = "Add Song"/>


</form>
<strong>

<ul id="playlist">


</ul>
</strong>
</body>
</html>
```

It works fine.

The problem is,

There is no need for window.onload since the function is trigerring on the button click. Thats the only thing i changed in the code. sorry for the delay

Comment: Why don't you explain what you changed and why, then this might qualify as a good answer.

Comment: Praveen, you are the man! You don't understand how frustrated I've been all day with this. & all I had to do was add onclick="handleButtonClick();"...I feel like such a moron. Next time I have a problem (which I'm sure will be very soon), I'll be sure to let you know. Thanks again man, you rock!

Comment: Hey Praveen, I'm trying to add songs, but as soon as I add the 3rd song they all disappear. Do you know why?

Comment: Sorry for the delay jaleel. gimme few mins i will let you kno if i can solve it.

Comment: [Image link](http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=oarfvm&s=6) for me its working fine. I added so many songs. check this link

Comment: Ohh, I didn't even realize you had removed "window.onload" & "function init". Thanks again, you're the best! Can you give me any tips on how to get rid of the bullet points & clean it up a little using CSS? All help is very much appreciated...

Comment: Just go through this website [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com) Then you don't need ask help to anyone. It will teach u a lot. What u want to do with that bullets? can u explain a little bit clear

Comment: As you are a newbie you dont know i think. Once your problem gets solved you have to select the answer as acceped by clicking on tick mark as green below that answer and make this question closed